# Import two dataframes from the same excel sheet in Rstudio as separated dataframes

Tags: r, excel

I have an excel file named "inner_merge" which in first sheet named "original" contains 2 separated dataframes exactly like in the image below. The first one has columns `id,type,state,zip` and the second `id1,type1,city1,state1,zip1,data,data_1,data_2` I would like to know how could I import those two in Rstudio as separated dataframes, avoiding to create two separated excel files.

[image]

Comment: @Adam yes, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `readxl::read_excel` you can use the `range` argument to specify which cells to read in. So you can use it once specifying columns A-E and again specifying columns H-P. See `?read_excel` and `?cell-specification` for details.

From your picture, you want something like this:

```
library(readxl)
library(cellranger)

df1 = read_excel(path, range = cell_cols("A:E"))
df2 = read_excel(path, range = cell_cols("H:P"))
```

Where `path` is the path to your excel file. You may also need to specify which sheet to read from if there are more than one.

Comment: thanks that works